# TwitterAPI account/update_profile_background_image not works

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using Abraham's PHP library to connect with the twitter api.
Im trying to update the background profile, after authentication doing the following:

```
$oauth = new TwitterOAuth($this->tw_key, $this->tw_secret, $this->tw_current_accessToken, $this->tw_current_accessSecret);
$oauth->host = $this->tw_host;
$result = $oauth->post('account/update_profile_background_image', array('image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_full_path))));
```

Path to image is correct.
I can do a `verify_credentials` perfectly, so the auth is not a problem.
It returns json coded array, like all is fine, but the background image param is not changing.
If i'm doing this using `array('image' => '@'.$image_full_path)` it gives 131 internal error, maybe because Abraham's library does not support multipart image uploads.

All other methods, like `account/update_profile_image` are working fine.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a size-limit, both in dimension and file size. Make sure your image is <800kb and smaller than 2048px at the largest side.

> The background image for the profile, base64-encoded. Must be a valid GIF, JPG, or PNG image of less than 800 kilobytes in size. Images with width larger than 2048 pixels will be forcibly scaled down. The image must be provided as raw multipart data, not a URL.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_background_image